# What happens inside when we write to a file without opening it?

Tags: c++, file, file-handling, iostream

for example if i write to a file which is not there where my << given string to write goes?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    fstream my_file;

    if (argc>1)
    {
            my_file.open("my_file.txt", ios::out);
            cout << "File1 created successfully!"<<endl;
    }


    my_file << "Guru99";
    my_file.close();
    cout<<"Done"<<endl;

    return 0; }
```

**Will it put it in memory or put it in dev/null kind of area?**

Comment: If the file is not open, then the stream will be in an error state, and anything you try to write will fail.

Comment: If i run the code it does not give any error, I don't want to write any thing (That works fine). was just curious if without opening and using << clogs anything in memory or not

Comment: Re. `"it does not give any error"`: you need to [check for errors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).

Comment: No, like I say, the stream will be in an error state and nothing will be stored anywhere.  In other words, `my_file.fail()` would return `true`.  Also, `my_file.is_open()` would return `false`.  There is no requirement for your program to display any kind of actual error automatically or hold your hand in any other way.  This behavior is well documented, and it's up to the programmer to handle errors however they choose.  Specifically in these cases, no exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Ok got it. But is there any way memeory is jammed this Kind of way ?  Any buffer where it continuously storing the given data to print in memory? Or it just ignores the given string to print and sets error flag to true?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to write to an `fstream` object that is not associated with a file (not open), your output will be discarded and the `failbit` will be set:

> If the output could not be generated, sets failbit, If exceptions on failbit are enabled in this stream's exception mask, throws ios_base::failure.

as described in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedOutputFunction.